# mysql query selecting wrong field

Tags: php, mysql, select

```
$something_else = mysql_query('SELECT image_id FROM items p LEFT JOIN list up ON p.item_id = up.item_id WHERE up.UserID =  "' . $user_id . '"');

     while ($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($something_else)){
         foreach($r as $item_id2)

$query ='DELETE FROM list WHERE UserID="' .$user_id. '" AND item_id="' .$item_id2. '"';}
```

This is for a product "wish list." Each is relative to a user. I can add to the wish list, but I can't delete the proper item. What this code is doing is deleting the last item on the list, or perhaps the item with the highest 'image_id'.

Either way, I'm not getting the relative 'image id' pertaining to the the associated item.

I'm pretty sure this should be enough information to solve the problem. I'm most certain my problem lies in the MySQL query:

`mysql_query('SELECT image_id FROM items p LEFT JOIN list up ON p.item_id = up.item_id WHERE up.UserID =  "' . $user_id . '"');`

Comment: Please, before you do anything else, read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because this is full of [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: thanks, appreciated...I'm aware, I haven't been able to do that yet, I've got to get it functioning first. This is only available inside a restricted area, so it's not available to the public.

Comment: Have you tried running the first query directly against the mysql database to make sure it returns anything? You're not capturing any errors, so you won't know if it's throwing an error.

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason, you shouldn't even be using the `mysql_query` interface in the first place. [PDO is significantly better](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and is future-proof. `mysql_query` is being removed in future versions of PHP, so you'll have to rewrite all your code anyway.

Comment: I know, but i'm trying to figure out the proper query.

Comment: that link is very helpful btw!

Answer (score 0):

first of all as mentioned before your queries are NOT secure, please use PDO. anyways try this :

```
$something_else = mysql_query('SELECT image_id FROM items p LEFT JOIN list up ON p.item_id = up.item_id WHERE up.UserID =  "' . $user_id . '"');

while ($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($something_else)) {    
    $query ='DELETE FROM list WHERE UserID="' .$user_id. '" AND item_id="' .$r['image_id'] . '"';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same item being deleted. It keeps deleting the item with the highest image_id, no matter which 'delete button' is pressed. I think my query is set up like that, and that is what needs to be changed.

Comment: well then you are missing a WHERE image_id=? in your query

Comment: image_id is what I'm trying to query

Comment: try the new code, but it's hard to help without knowing what you are trying to do.

Comment: The query as above would completely empty a user's list. There should be no reason at all for the first 'SELECT' query. You need to pass the item_id and UserID as shown on line 4, but nothing else.